# Add leading slash for certain directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

A client has about a hundred html files that contain links to resources that need a leading slash. For example, the link css/main.min.css needs to be /css/main.min.css. The same apples to resources in scripts/ and images/. Instead of searching and replacing the hundreds of instances, I'd like to handle it via .htaccess. I've got the following, which sort of works but only for resources matching the first rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

RewriteRule scripts/(.*) /scripts/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule images/(.*) /images/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule css/(.*) /css/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (scripts|images|css)/(.*) /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Because RewriteCond works only for the next first RewriteRule

Comment: Perfect! Thanks much.